# How to use Named group as input in Regular expression

Tags: c#, regex

String is having length and followed by msg as integer. Using named group i can assign the length values but how can i use that captured named group as input to process further.

example "Length 2 01 02"

From the above example,
output is length = 2 and msg="01 02"

```
Regex.Match(stringval, $@"(Length ?<{length}>(\d+))\s+(?<{msg}>(\d+\s)<{length}>")
```

From the above expression i can capture length values but i cant use it as input to capture the msg data

Comment: I don't think regex is the right tool for this.  Just split the string on spaces.

Comment: Is this string same for all your inputs? Is it in same format always, like `Length <lengthValue> <msgValue> <msgValue>`

Comment: regex often creates unreadable and difficult to maintain code.  Useful though it is I think it can be overkill in some cases.

Comment: @PrasadTelkikar, <lengthValue> is count of msg values, in above example count is 2 and "01 02" is msg

Comment: I agree with prasad, can you not just split on space?  Much easier to read.  You can then check the number of values = the count if you need to.

Answer (score 1):

You understood something wrong.

> Braces mark a group - A group can be named at the opening braces.

Here a complete step-by-step example:

```cs
string input = "Length 2 01 02";

int length = 2;
string msg = "01 02";

// Let's declare a regex to match our input:
Match m = Regex.Match(input, @"^Length \d+\s+\d+\s+\d+$");

if (m.Success)
    Console.WriteLine("Match!"); // Works

// Now let's declare groups to access
m = Regex.Match(input, @"^Length (\d+)\s+(\d+)\s+(\d+)$");

if (m.Success)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Match!"); // Works
    Console.WriteLine(m.Groups[0].ToString()); // Group 0 is complete matched string
    Console.WriteLine(m.Groups[1].ToString()); // first braces..
    Console.WriteLine(m.Groups[2].ToString()); // second.. etc..
    Console.WriteLine(m.Groups[3].ToString());
}

// Now let's name our groups. (xxx) = group, (?<name>xxx) = group with name "name"
m = Regex.Match(input, @"^Length (?<FirstGroup>\d+)\s+(?<SecondGroup>\d+)\s+(?<ThirdGroup>\d+)$");

if (m.Success)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Match!"); // Works
    Console.WriteLine(m.Groups["FirstGroup"].ToString()); // Now we access the groups by their names
    Console.WriteLine(m.Groups["SecondGroup"].ToString());
    Console.WriteLine(m.Groups["ThirdGroup"].ToString());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `.Split()` and `Linq` operations

```
string input = "Length 2 01 02";
string[] str = input.Split(' ');
var result = $"{string.Join("=", str.Take(2))} msg = {string.Join(" ", str.Skip(2))}";
```

Output:

[image]

Here,

`input.Split(' ')` : This will split your string into an array of string considering `_`(Space) as a delimiter.

`string.Join("=", str.Take(2))` : This will first take first two elements from array and join it with `=`.

`{string.Join(" ", str.Skip(2))` : This will skip first two array elements and join rest of elements by adding space in between each element